# custom field serialization using jacson

Tags: java, jackson

I want to serialize few fields of my class in custom way using jackson. So i wrote a custom serializer for this.But my problem is i am not able to get the name of the field in custom serializer. My POJO class is

```
public static class Foo {
public String foo = "a";
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
public String bar = "b";
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
public String foobar = "c";
}
```

And my custom serializer class is

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String>
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(String t, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws         IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        if(field.name.equals("a"))
            //do this
        else if(filed.name.equals("b")) 
            //do that
    }

 }
```

Here i want get the name of field which is being serialized.
How can i get the name of fields "a" and "b" in custom serializer ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is not possible now. But you can create two separate serializers for each property. I know, this a little workaround, but it should work.

Comment: I thought of that, but i have to serialize many fields in that way,so it seems to be impossible to do so.By the way thanks for the reply